# Multiple monitors (more than 2) not working on Fedora 38; how can I fix this?

Tags: fedora, multi-monitor

Having used Fedora as a server since Red Hat 1.1, I FINALLY decided to replace my aging user-interface Windows 7 with Fedora Workstation but I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to honor all 6 of the monitors.

It's not that I loved Windows, I stopped "upgrading" at 7, but it worked fine and I've been running six identical monitors on three identical twin cards for about 22 years now (on various versions of Windows). Hey, it's a tool that's worked as a user interface while I muck around with Unix / Linux servers and it let me do office-stuff the same way "the rest of the world does."

...The Windows 7 system was on an older but not ancient ASUS Intel-CPU motherboard and it's got a hardware issue I don't want to have to fix. So, for the change I took a younger ASUS motherboard with an AMD CPU of about the same class (3.6 ghz, lots of cores), fed it 64G of ram, and moved the same exact video cards over between the boards.

In setting up the system, I was patient - wanted to know it would work: I took another extant Fedora (Server) disk and used it to see if the video cards worked and it was able to use all the displays, so I figured all would go well even though the setup area only had two I could test at a time. All cards checked out, and even two from the same card and also one on two different cards. So, I figured it would work.

I then added the Fedora Workstation and was also able to test two displays at a time - so far so good.

But when I tried to use more, it just wouldn't let me configure them. At first, I tried it with six all at once, it just hung and I was forced to power it off to get its attention. Later, with fewer displays, I was able to log in through the net so I didn't have to power it off or hit reset to restart. Eventually I've got it working on TWO monitors, a far cry from the 6 I want / need to be using!

Note that I'm skipping all the details about what was on the displays that were powered up and connected but not (yet?) recognized. In short, they all displayed something, just not coherently, and the incoherence changed in odd ways. ... But I don't think that matters, though it might.

... I figured Linux was mature enough for this by now? If I'm not wrong, how do I fix this?

I'm happy to share whatever software / hardware details about this setup that may be required and will respond - and add the data to the question - upon request.

The only anomaly of which I am aware is:

It's Fedora Core 38 starting with Server with nearly all of workstation installed, too. However, the groupinstall of "Fedora Workstation" balked at some conflicting hardware related packages from Fedora Server that come with Fedora Workstation, so I went with the ones from Server which were younger.

Beyond that, I'm not sure what exactly to share.

**Hardware**

Three video cards: NVIDIA model P1310
Motherboard: ASUS Pro WS X570-ACE
Displays: ASUS VS239H-P  (Not so sure about the H-P part as both are on the ID tags)

Need / want more, just ask!

Comment: the only thing we know about your setup is the CPU and RAM ... these two things won't help debug your display problem, since you're likely to be using some graphics cards (I'm assuming at least two if you want 6 monitors) - please edit the question and add information about these graphics cards

Comment: So, 3 identical cards, when you succeed with 2 displays, is it 2 displays on any one card? 2 displays on 2 different cards? using the dual DVI? the HDMI (apparently they have HDMI though the pictures suggest otherwise) - have you tried just a single card in the system at a time, to ensure they all work?

Comment: @JaromandaX  I didn't try EVERY combination but I tried two on the same card and one each on different cards. And, I tried all three cards.

Comment: so all three cards are fine, as long as only two monitors are attached

Comment: @JaromandaX ...As I said, I didn't try every combination but yes, that appears to be correct; every pair I tried worked, though I did a reboot between and, as I noted in the original posting, I hadn't installed a windowing system yet. ... A small detail I may have left out was that on every _reboot,_ during shutdown, windowing system or not, there was some small "Fedora" tag on all windows as the system shut itself down, even though when running the screens had obviously wrong display rates, etc. ... MY take is that this is a pure software issue pertaining to the display manager somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work...

...But NOT the way I wanted to: ***I went to a single card*** which has 6 monitor support.

And along the way of solving [a different problem,](https://serverfault.com/questions/1143048/fedora-38-cant-open-an-x11-display-between-two-nearly-identical-systems-how-d/1143589#1143589) I discovered that this is likely an issue with `Waveland`, the supposed replacement for `X-11` that's now the default for the `GNOME` desktop system. I say that because in various places they state that as of this writing `Waveland` is still under development and some applications and behaviors "don't work as expected," etc. ... There's even a recommendation to go back to `X-11` in these instances, though I haven't taken the time to try the older hardware - and probably won't at this point.